# how to connect local symfony project to remote docker service

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerized development environment in a remote server:

```
iig_docker_postgres_adminer             entrypoint.sh docker-php-e ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp
iig_docker_postgres_nginx               /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp
iig_docker_postgres_php                 docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp
iig_docker_postgres_postgres_database   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```

This development stack is available using this URL:

http://syy0ana001.hpmetier.sf.intra.laposte.fr:8080

My postgres `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgres:12
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  database:
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_postgres_database
    build:
      context: ./postgres
    hostname: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: dbtest
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - symfony
```

POSTGRES_PORT=5432

Now, I'm trying to connect to postgres database from local Symfony project.

I tried:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root:124524..@http://syy0ana001.hpmetier.sf.intra.laposte.fr:5432/dbtest?serverVersion=12&charset=utf8
```

It doesn't work.

Then I inspected the postgres volume:

```
docker inspect iig_docker_postgres_postgres_database
```

I got:

```
"Networks": {
                "symfony": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "database",
                        "ecc337072ae2"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "305da1272e2238216593c6c44352aa7958c1f958240487aece8c4223e133ea45",
                    "EndpointID": "e0ea773bc69025d1796ca4fff54adb3a6859e0de7afdb42619734893fab98883",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.96.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.96.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 20,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:60:05",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
```

Then I tried  :

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:admin@192.168.96.5:5432/dbtest?serverVersion=12&charset=utf8"

volumes:
  symfony_dockerized_app_sync:
  db_app:


networks:
  symfony:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

It doesn't work

How can I correctly connect to remote docker service from my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this line correctly:

```
iig_docker_postgres_postgres_database   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432->8084/tcp
```

I would say the problem is in your docker-compose.yml. You are mapping host port 5432 to container internal port 8084. Does your postgres instance in the container run on port 8084?

Your container also exposes port 5432 but you are not mapping that one.

After you check this, make sure that the port 5432 is open in the firewall of your server and everything should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer,  i updated my question,  currently postgres container use 8084, i don't understand why i should mapped the port 5432 , how can i do that ?

Comment: I see your Dockerfile. Only because you declare `EXPOSE 8084` that does not mean that your postgres will run on that port. I would suggest to leave the postgres run on 5432 inside the container (it is running there at the moment, anyway). Then on the host you can map a different port if you want (for security reasons for example. Actions for you: remove the EXPOSE declaration and replace 8084 with 5432 everywhere

Comment: i did, i updated my question, i'm using 5432,   i still can't connected to postgres container from my local project

Comment: note that i'm using bridge drive network with external true

Comment: you need to check that the port is open. from outside can you use `telnet` or `nc` and see that you get a response on the port 5432? Also do the same on the machine where the container is running to validate that you can connect to port 5432 on the host (if this works and from outside not then it is a firewall issue)

Comment: thank you, now the port is open,  currently i get a symfony error : An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver  ,   any idea?

Comment: sorry, that's out of my expertise :) However, you don't need to declare the networks in docker-compose.yml. Docker-compose already does that for you. So you can safely remove all the network definitions and references that you have in there. Hopefully this helps